# Can't getStockItem magento 2.3.1

Tags: stock, magento2.3.1, stock-status

Block

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block\Product;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Stickycart extends Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    protected $_stockItemRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }

    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    } 
}
```

Template

```
$currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct();
$id = $currentProduct->getId();
$_productStock = $block->getStockItem($id);
if($_productStock->getIsInStock()){
...
}
```

But it show a bug:

```
The stock item with the "140" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again.
```

I have checked that product in backend in Catalog but it's instock with qty is 465.

Comment: check if that product id is 140

Comment: Yes, Please check my screen:
http://prntscr.com/ojpqa4

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try using this** `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface`

> Update your code with the following code

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block\Product;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Stickycart extends Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    protected $stockRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }

    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
    }
}
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: It work fine. Thank you!

Comment: glad it worked.

Comment: @MohitRane , i am facing the sameissue , is there any explanation why the issue happens in the first place .